# MouseEvent coordinates on Qlabel with Image

Tags: c++, qt

so i dont know how to add a mouseevent ( if i click the label with image selected to add x,y coordinates of the mouse on the tableWidget and the coordinates to be drawed on the image ( green/red dots)

[image]

for now i only can open a ascii file with coordinates and image. i need your help with mouseevent and draw the points on the image

```
void design::on_loadtext1_clicked() {
ui->merge->setText("merge");
QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            this,
            tr("Open File"),
            "C://",
            "Text File(*.txt)"

         );
QFile file(filename);
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) { QMessageBox::information(nullptr,"Info",file.errorString());
}
QTextStream in(&file);
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;
 // double xn = 532;
  int row=0;
  QString line;
  ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(30);
  ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);

  while(!in.atEnd()) {
      line = in.readLine();
      QStringList s = line.split(" ");
      x = s.at(0).toDouble();
      y = s.at(1).toDouble();
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, new TableItem(tr("%1").arg(x)));
         ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, new TableItem(tr("%1").arg(y)));

      row++;
  } }
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: ah, my bad i want to do all of these: When i click a label with an image selected i want to add the x,y mouse coordinates on that tablewidget below and the clicked image to be edited with a red dot or circle when i press the leftclick on label

Comment: edit your question and add the necessary information there

Comment: Subclass `QLabel` and overload `mouseReleaseEvent()`.

Comment: how can i subclass?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw an ellipse on QLabel at mouse click position, this code should get you started:

First, as proposed, subclass `QLabel`:

*.h* file

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    MyLabel(QWidget* parent=nullptr);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e);

private:
    QPixmap *pix;
};
```

Then create `pixmap` in constructor and implement drawing on `mouseClickEvent`:

*.cpp* file

```
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
    pix = new QPixmap(200,200);
    pix->fill(Qt::white);
    setPixmap(*pix);
}

void MyLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    int xPos, yPos;
    if(e->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        xPos = e->pos().x();
        yPos = e->pos().y();
    }

    QPainter painter(pix);
    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.drawEllipse(xPos, yPos, 3, 3);

    setPixmap(*pix);

    QLabel::mousePressEvent(e);
}
```

Then just create an instance of `MyLabel` in `MainWindow`:

```
label = new MyLabel(this);
label->setGeometry(0,0,200,200);
```

Don't forget declaration in `mainwindow.h`:

```
MyLabel *label;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesnt affect my label, so i cant save it with the drawn points

Comment: @ŔaduVătase well, it does affect the label created and used like shown in an example above. I've tested the code

Comment: it effects but not directly, from that 200x200 square.. i need it to edit just the main label.. named "label" in my code. SEE : https://imgur.com/a/Em8sih2

Comment: @ŔaduVătase you shouldn't be using QLabel object in your form if you plan on using my code. Delete your label from .ui file, create an instance of MyLabel as shown above and work with it instead.

Comment: where i should put the : label = new MyLabel(this);
label->setGeometry(0,0,200,200);

Comment: @ŔaduVătase you should declare a pointer to MyLabel object in your design.h file and put those two lines in your constructor in design.cpp and work with it instead of your qlabel object from .ui. It all was mentioned in my answer and comments

Comment: @ŔaduVătase i recommend you learn some basic principles of programming with qt. [This thread](http://example.com) should be helpfu to you. Don't forget to mark this post as an answer since it solves your problem.

Comment: got it now it works but now i need to save that image edited and add coordinates on tablewidget